# Change file permission to be read and write

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I am new to file/folder permissions in Unix and have a problem.  I have a directory with all the files and folders permissions set to 0755.  When I try to upload those files to my server and try to edit, delete, or rename them, permission is denied.

After some research online I found that there is a solution to change all the files and folders to 0777 so that everyone can read/write but, of course, I don't want to do that because that may cause security issues.

Please note that I don't have SSH access to the host.  What I'm doing right now is changing the file permission on my local Linux machine and uploading the modified files to the remote server.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: do you have access if you upload a file with 0777? Are you using ftp?

Answer (score 0):

How are you copying the files over to the remote server ?

If you are using rsync then use the -a switch to preserve it.
cp -p would preserve the file permissions.

You can read about these commands here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339287/copy-or-rsync-command